# Include finding directory when not specified

Tags: php

Does anybody know why this is happening?

My directory looks something like this:

```
root
    - css
    - includes
        - header.php
        - footer.php
    - js
    - index.php
```

There is only 1 PHP file in the root folder.

Then my PHP script is simply:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>

<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

This is finding the header and footer in the includes folder when surely I have to reference it as:

```
<?php
include 'includes/header.php';
?>
```

Incidentally when I do this it is still finding the file correctly. I can't work out how it is finding it regardless. Have I missed something about PHP searching sub directories if it can't find an included file???

Comment: `include './includes/header.php';`

Comment: Could you check **include_path** in your phpinfo.

Comment: [include_path](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) set somewhere?

Comment: I'd say your `includes` folder is in the [include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)

Comment: It was indeed set in phpinfo file thank you! I never knew this, that was purely a happy accident!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You very likely have the "includes" directory in your `include_path`, if you echo it out you will see:

```
echo get_include_path();
```

You can change this using `set_include_path` too, see here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: Thank you. you are very correct! I literally never knew this, that was just a happy accident then :)

Comment: Glad it makes sense now. I remember tripping over this a good number of years back :)